# Stop async operations on window close

Tags: swift, cocoa, appdelegate

In my app delegate I have put the callback to stop the program when the window is shut.

```
 func applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed(sender: NSApplication) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
```

This doesn't work however because (I assume) there is an async bluetooth task running. What is the best way to stop everything running and clean up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this approach

```
[NSApp performSelector:@selector(terminate:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
```